# Custom Memory Allocator - How to find the required alignment for a platform?

Tags: microcontroller, c, memory, programming, alignment

I'm building a portable arena allocator for embedded systems.
Like for `malloc`, one of the requirements is to return a pointer aligned with the memory.

The question is: Is there a way to know at compile time what are the memory alignment requirements for a given platform in C?

I've seen this code snippets floating around, but I haven't find any documentation to support it's validity:

```
#ifndef DEFAULT_ALIGNMENT
   #define DEFAULT_ALIGNMENT (2*sizeof(void *))
#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`malloc` is required to return a pointer properly aligned to hold an object of *any type*. Which means it must be aligned *at least* as the largest scalar type. Luckily C is defining such a type as `max_align_t`.
In the [C11 standard (draft) section 6.2.8](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.8) it says:

> A fundamental alignment is represented by an alignment less than or
> equal to the greatest alignment supported by the implementation in all
> contexts, which is equal to _Alignof (max_align_t).

Test it out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h> // <- this required for max_align_t

int main(void) {
    printf("%zu\n",  _Alignof (max_align_t));
    return 0;
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/cDSVtH

Comment: Thanks, Eugene, that's exactly what I needed.